# Is there a way to automatically draw curved edges using tikz's algorithmic graph drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, trees, tikz-graphdrawing

I can easily draw automatically-laid out trees in tikz, but with straight edges between nodes. I'd like for edges to be automatically curved similar to this tree drawing software: https://mindnode.com. An example is:

Approximately Desired Image
[image: tree graph with dummy nodes and curved edges]

With tikz, I can draw the below but is there any way for it to automatically bend/curve edges for aesthetics / saving space? Can one also colorize siblings / descendants automatically without implementing a custom Lua drawing script?

Tikz Image:

[image: Tikz tree graph with dummy nodes and straight edges]

Code:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=, every node/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=west, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow'=right, fresh nodes, tail anchor=east, head
  anchor=west, level sep=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
{
  Root -> {
    a -> {d, e, f},
    b -> {g, h},
    c -> {i -> {l, m}, j, k}
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use \draw [->] (a) to [out=0, in=180] (b); see slide 40 at http://www.computational-logic.org/content/study/master/documents/softskills_tikz.pdf

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @Julian_W: Thanks, but per Section 27.1 of the [Tikz manual, latest, 3.0.1.a](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanual_3.0.1a.pdf) In the graphdrawing package, you cannot use \draw inside \graph because (as I understand) node creation is deferred. My goal is to maintain the concise -> syntax, just have curved edges handled by automatic layout, if that makes sense?

Comment: Have you considered Forest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do at least some of this with the graph-drawing facilities. Probably, use of `color classes` would facilitate greater automation. However, I'm not immediately sure how to make that work and the manual is extremely vague on what is possible and how. (Or I just don't understand its approach - I admit to finding the graph-drawing stuff almost entirely opaque.)

Here's an example:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [>=, every node/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=west, minimum size=0.75cm}, line width=1pt]
  \graph [tree layout, simple, grow'=right, level sep=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
  {
    Root -> {
      a ->[draw=cyan] {d, e, f},
      b ->[draw=blue] {g, h},
      c ->[draw=green] {i -> {l, m}, j, k}
    };
    i -> [bend left, green] l;
    i -> [bend right, green] m;
    Root -> [bend left, cyan] a;
    Root -> [blue] b;
    Root -> [bend right, green] c;
    a -> [bend left, cyan] d;
    a -> [bend right, cyan] f;
    b -> [bend left, blue] g;
    b -> [bend right, blue] h;
    c -> [bend left, green] i;
    c -> [bend right, green] k;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bending, coloured edges with Ti*k*Z graph-drawing]

Personally, I wouldn't bother with the graph-drawing stuff for drawing trees. If you need arbitrary graphs, it is different - options are very limited. But trees have lots of support from specialised packages, many of which support very concise syntax, albeit not the same syntax as the graph-drawing stuff provided by Ti*k*Z.

For example, with Forest, I can define a style - `tracks`, say - which allows me to write

```
\begin{forest}
  tracks
  [Root
    [a, colour me down=cyan!50!blue [d][e][f] ]
    [b, colour me down=blue [g][h] ]
    [c, colour me down=green!75!black [i [l][m] ][j][k] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

to produce

[image: Forest <code>tracks</code>]

which is particularly useful if you need to use a style for many trees. The colouring could be built into the style, but I assumed this was more likely to vary than other elements, so just used a simple convenience wrapper for use in specifying colouring for a particular tree.

In this case, the colouring is specified for each of the root's children and automatically propagated to each child's descendants.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\forestset{
  tracks/.style={
    for tree={
      grow'=0,
      l sep'+=50pt,
      s sep'+=30pt,
      font=\bfseries\sffamily,
      edge path'={
        (!u.parent anchor) -- ($(.child anchor)-(20pt,0pt)$) -- (.child anchor)
      },
      edge+={ultra thick, rounded corners}
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for descendants={
        edge label/.process={ Ow {content} {node [above, font=\bfseries\sffamily, anchor=south, pos=.75] {##1}} },
        content=,
        shape=coordinate,
      },
      where={>Ow+P {n children} {isodd(##1)} }{
        calign=child edge,
        calign primary child/.process={ Ow+n {n children} {(##1+1)/2} }
      }{}  
    },
  },
  colour me/.style={
    #1,
    edge+={#1},
  },
  colour me down/.style={
    for tree={colour me=#1},
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  tracks
  [Root
    [a, colour me down=cyan!50!blue [d][e][f] ]
    [b, colour me down=blue [g][h] ]
    [c, colour me down=green!75!black [i [l][m] ][j][k] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want the labels coloured, but only the edges, use `edge+={draw=#1}` rather than `edge+={#1}` in the `colour me` style and maybe delete the previous line containing `#1`.

Comment: Hmm, so in the first example, still using graphdrawing, bending could be done automatically if we could glean the information of whether the child was within the first n/2 (bend left), last n/2 (bend right) or == n/2 (don't bend) children. I know graphdrawing defers graph creation so perhaps this is possible... As for your second example, I can't get it to compile when I include tracks within the forest definition, error: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgf@temp <to be read again> 1 1.44 \end{forest}." If I remove the tracks line after \begin{forest} it works, though...

Comment: @menger I don't really understand what you did which didn't work. Does the example work as-is for you? If you don't use a style, but include the style definition in the tree, you need to adjust the argument specifiers. Use of `.style` doubles the hashes, so removing the definition from `.style` requires halving them. However, I'm not sure if that's what you did or not. I recommend keeping the style out of the `forest` environment in most cases, because some modifications are possible only if some stuff is set outside `forest` and it is generally easier to keep stuff together. At least, for me.

Comment: @menger I don't know whether you can detect that with the graph-drawing stuff or not. I don't really have an understanding of how graph-drawing works in Ti*k*Z. I can do certain things, but it is mostly beyond my ken :(. In particular, I don't find the documentation terribly helpful - it suggests experiments, but it takes lots of trial-and-error for me to figure out even quite simple things. Probably just me, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You are welcome :) could be a little more automated and also needs some finetuning, but I gotta go for now. Feedback is also welcome!

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5,yscale=0.5]

\fill[black!20!white] (0,0) rectangle (16,11);

\coordinate (root) at (2,5);

\coordinate (a) at (6,8);
    \coordinate (d) at (10,9);
    \coordinate (e) at (10,8);
    \coordinate (f) at (10,7);
\coordinate (b) at (6,5);
    \coordinate (g) at (10,5.5);
    \coordinate (h) at (10,4.5);
\coordinate (c) at (6,2);
    \coordinate (i) at (10,3);
        \coordinate (l) at (13,3.5);
        \coordinate (m) at (13,2.5);
    \coordinate (j) at (10,2);
    \coordinate (k) at (10,1);

\node [above=0.05of a] {a};
    \node [above=0.05of d] {d};
    \node [above=0.05of e] {e};
    \node [above=0.05of f] {f};
\node [above=0.05of b] {b};
    \node [above=0.05of g] {g};
    \node [above=0.05of h] {h};
\node [above=0.05of c] {c};
    \node [above=0.05of i] {i};
        \node [above=0.05of l] {l};
        \node [above=0.05of m] {m};
    \node [above=0.05of j] {j};
    \node [above=0.05of k] {k};

\draw [out=45, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,blue] (root) to (a);
\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,blue!40!white](root) to (b);
\draw [out=-45, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,green](root) to (c);

\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,blue!90!white](a) to (d) -- ++(2,0);
\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,blue!90!white](a) to (e) -- ++(2,0);
\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,blue!90!white](a) to (f) -- ++(2,0);

\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,blue!40!white](b) to (g) -- ++(2,0);
\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,blue!40!white](b) to (h) -- ++(2,0);

\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,green](c) to (i);
\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,green](c) to (j) -- ++(2,0);
\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,green](c) to (k) -- ++(2,0);

\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,green](i) to (l) -- ++(2,0);
\draw [out=0, in=180,line width = 0.1cm,green](i) to (m) -- ++(2,0);

\node at (root) [fill=white, rounded rectangle] {Root};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As it is, commenting out `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`, `\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}` and `\usegdlibrary{trees}` your code compiles without issue under pdfLaTeX. I would streamline the code a bit by using some TikZ styles.

Comment: `\coordinate [label=above:a] (a) at (x,y);` would spare you the trouble of having both a `\coordinate` and a `\node`. And as all the to-paths have the same `in` angle, you could set `\begin{tikzpicture}[in=180,...]`

Comment: Thank you; this is helpful! But my goal is to maintain concise syntax and not think about coordinates.

Comment: I prefer styling before automation, but thats my personal taste I guess. Also usually the automated version usually needs some manual tweaking.